# How to add libraries path to the ./configure command?

Tags: compiling

I would like `./configure` to link to a library and some include files. My library is stored in `/home/foo/sw/lib/` and my files are stored in `/home/foo/sw/include`.

`./configure --help` throws out the following:

Some influential environment variables:

```
  CC           C compiler command
  CFLAGS       C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS      linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a 
               nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS         libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS     (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if 
               you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP          C preprocessor
```

I have tried various combinations:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/foo/sw -I</home/foo/sw/include> -L</home/foo/sw/lib/>
./configure --prefix=/home/foo/sw -I=/home/foo/sw/include -L=/home/foo/sw/lib/
./configure --prefix=/home/foo/sw -I/home/foo/sw/include -L/home/foo/sw/lib/
etc..
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right. If anyone can help me out, that would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You missed the meaning of

> Some influential **environment variables**:

So you set them as an environment variable; configure determines LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS by checking config files and the environment. You can set them like this ...

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include/'
export LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/'
./configure
```

or as a one-liner:

```
env CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include/' LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/' ./configure
```

Please note that it is possible that you cannot use subdirectories under `/home/foo/sw/lib/`

f.e. putting your library in `/home/foo/sw/lib/bar/` might show you a `lib not found`error.

However you can use multiple entries:

`LDFLAGS="-L/home/foo/sw/lib/ -L/home/foo/bar/lib/"`

Comment: Maybe CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include:$CPPFLAGS' just in case something is out there ;)

Comment: Hi, Rinzwind. I am confused about the difference between `LDFLAGS=-L` and `LIBS=-l`. According to the help, they seems to be the same thing. Is there any difference?

Comment: @user15964 `-L` refers to a directory to search for libraries while `-l` informs the linker to link against a specific library (to find which it will search the supplied `-L` directories alongside the default set.

Comment: Why is there a `/` after `LDFLAGS` but not after `CPPFLAGS` ? Is that a typo, or is it important?

Comment: not perse, both work and no. The / at the end signifies it is a directory but it  is not needed too include.

Comment: Wanted to add that, depending upon what's being compiled, the user might have to add their `lib` directory to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Does not work for cairo