# Octave-4.0.0 Configuration step warnings in Ubuntu 15.04 (HDF5/jni.h not found)

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, openjdk, configure, octave

I am trying to install Octave-4.0.0 from source following the instructions from the [wiki page](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#Compiling_from_source). I have installed every single dependency (optional too) mentioned on that page. In the configuration step I used

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial \
            LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/hdf5/serial
```

as given there to avoid potential HDF5 library related problems. Doing this, I got (initially I was getting JAVA_HOME warning, which I then fixed):

```
configure: WARNING: Include file <jni.h> not found.  Octave will not be able to call Java methods.
configure: 
configure: NOTE: Libraries or auxiliary programs may be skipped if they are
configure: NOTE: not found OR if they are missing required features on your
configure: NOTE: system.
```

Thereafter, to fix this, I tried using [how to add jni.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529804/3083243) and [adding libraries to ./configure path](https://askubuntu.com/a/386372/374847). But, if I follow that configure command with

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include
```

or even use both the `CPPFLAGS` settings together (that is, in the same `./configure` line), I get this:

```
configure: WARNING: HDF5 library not found.  Octave will not be able to save or load HDF5 data files.
configure: WARNING: Include file jni.h not found.  Octave will not be able to call Java methods. 
configure:   
configure: NOTE: Libraries or auxiliary programs may be skipped if they are
configure: NOTE: not found OR if they are missing required features on your
configure: NOTE: system.
```

How should I pass these warnings and install Octave-4.0.0 gracefully (target: image processing)?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to define multiple `CPPFLAGS` variables on the command line, only the last one will apply. Instead, you should be able to combine *both* include directives into a *single* variable as a quoted string:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include"
```

e.g.

```
./configure \
  CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include" \
  LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/hdf5/serial
```

Comment: Thanks, but still getting jni.h warning. Is there something wrong with my JAVA_PATH instead or something? My `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-sun/bin` (though I have had set it openjdk-7-amd64 many-a-times)!

Comment: If your `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-sun`, then why try to build Octave with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`?