# Error in Caffe Installation in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiling, caffe

While compiling Caffe in Ubuntu 16.04, I got the following error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
Makefile:563: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed  
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

Please suggest a way to successfully install caffe by removing this error?

Comment: Did you install the indicated [General dependencies](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html), in particular `libhdf5-serial-dev`?

Comment: All the dependencies are already installed!!

Comment: It may be essentially the same issue as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649401/octave-4-0-0-configuration-step-warnings-in-ubuntu-15-04-hdf5-jni-h-not-found) i.e. that Ubuntu's packaging has moved the hdf5 serial header files and libraries into subdirectories. Try adding an explicit link flag to your configuration e.g. `./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/hdf5/serial`

Comment: I did that still while compilation,it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, 
in 'Makefile.config'
change line 94 and 95 to

**LINE 94:** INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include  /usr/include/hdf5/serial

**LINE 95:** LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial