# How do I add to my compile and link lines?

Tags: compiling

I am new to Linux and trying to install cuDNN on my Ubuntu computer. The installation instructions contain the following:

"Add (installpath) to your build and link process by adding -I(installpath) to your compile line and -L(installpath) -lcudnn to your link line."

How do I add paths to my compile and link lines? I'm guessing there are other terms for these because my search results haven't turned up anything that addressed both paths.

Comment: This question may help you out: http://askubuntu.com/q/386315/57576

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like it's export CPPFLAGS=-I/my/dir/ and export LDFLAGS=-L/my/dir -lcudnn. The first one works but the second tells me that -lcudnn is not a valid identifier

Comment: Do you have a link to the installation archive / file and instructions? And perhaps try `CPPFLAGS='-I/home/foo/sw/include' LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/' LIBS='-lcudnn' ./configure`

Comment: I've give that a try. Here are the instructions: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v5/rc/cudnn_install.txt?autho=1460851211_c67cac0710b5291d04f4e9b60911ab7c&file=cudnn_install.txt

Comment: At fist it gave me "No such file or directory", but after I removed './configure' it seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: And it compiles now?

Comment: Obviously, I don't know much about this, but my understanding is that I don't need to compile cuDNN, just follows those instructions and then Caffe will use it when it compiles (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html). Like I said, I'm not sure about this so I may be way off.